# My TrackPad is moving randomly

Tags: mac, mouse, touchpad

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13 Inch, end of 2013), and the trackpad is not working, basically, the mouse is moving randomly for no reason, I restarted my mac, the mouse worked for about 3 minutes, and after the issue happened, and it's very annoying! P.S. when I connect it to an external mouse, it works fine, but the problem is that it's not my mouse, and I don't want to buy a new mouse.

Comment: Sounds to me like it's take your MBP for repair, or buy a mouse. Has hints of water-spill, or at minimum, dirt-buildup.

Comment: If it just does it while you are typing it might be your palms. Also make sure the surface is clean.